# select by attribute on shapefiles with open-source python modules

Tags: python, open-source-gis, select-by-attribute

I usually use ArcGis 9.3.1, but when running a python script that includes Select_by_attribute (from gp), the script runs very very slowly. Is there a way I can perform a select-by-attribute on a opensource-python-module (such as shapely?)? Will it be faster?

Answer (score 3):

You are likely to see faster results by adding appropriate attribute indexes to your shapefile as outlined at [Modifying indexes in shapefiles by indexing an attribute](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/by_indexing_an_attribute/00560000000m000000/), or moving your data to a FileGDB and adding indexes there.

Any performance benefits of using an opensource option are likely to be outweighed by having to then integrate the results of the query back into your ESRI geoprocessing - unless you want to move the whole process to opensource. Shapely is for manipulating geometry, to select features by attributes you could use [OGR and the Shapefile driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_shapefile.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the python modules, but I've used the [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) utility for subsetting records from shapefiles by attribrute selection and found it to be [orders of magnitude](http://www.maphew.com/Projects/ipy_and_arcgisscripting) faster than using arcgis geoprocessing (10 seconds versus 6 minutes). Example [ogr2ogr selection](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html) query:

```
SELECT * from polylayer WHERE prop_value > 220000.0 ORDER BY prop_value DESC
```

To keep it in the arcgis world, I've seen `gp.Select_analysis` be faster than `gp.Select_by_attribute`. I've not investigated to find out if this is always true or just a momentary peculiarity.